# AttributeError when trying to match input with content from a class in Python 3

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, attributeerror

I have a class containing information that I want to use in in an `input`:

```
class Weapon(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value, desc):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.desc = desc

sword = Weapon("Sword", 2, "A regular sword.")
shield = Weapon("Axe", 2, "A hefty axe.")

EquippedWeapon = ""

while True:
    action = input("? ").lower().split()

    if action[0] == "equip":
        if action[1] in action[0].name:
            EquippedWeapon = action[0].name
            print(EquippedWeapon)
            break
        else:
            print("Try again.")
    else:
        print("Error")
        break
```

However, when trying to run this I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`action` is produced from `str.split()`, so it's a `list` of `str`. `str` objects don't have a `name` attribute. I'm guessing you want the user to be able to enter `equip Sword` and have that print the instance `sword`.

Usually, you'd want to make a lookup `dict` for this, replacing:

```
sword = Weapon("Sword", 2, "A regular sword.")
shield = Weapon("Axe", 2, "A hefty axe.")
```

with something like:

```
equipment = [Weapon("Sword", 2, "A regular sword."),
             Weapon("Axe", 2, "A hefty axe.")]
equipment_by_name = {eq.name.lower(): eq for eq in equipment}
```

then changing your code to convert from the string name of the equipment to the object itself looking it up, e.g.:

```
if action[0] == "equip":
    try:
        # Do simple lookup to convert from name to useful object
        equipped_weapon = equipment_by_name[action[1].lower()]
    except LookupError:
        # You'll get here if they failed to specify a name, causing action[1]
        # to produce an IndexError, or if the name doesn't match the available
        # equipment, producing a KeyError, both of which are subclasses of LookupError
        print("Try again.")
    else:
        # Note: You haven't defined __repr__ or __str__ on the class, so this
        # print won't be very useful
        print(equipped_weapon)
else:
    print("Error")
    break
```